# Join in Pandas Dataframe using conditional join statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I am trying to join two dataframes with the following data:

df1

[image: df1]

df2

[image: df2]

I want to join these two dataframes on the condition that if 'col2' of **df2** is blank/NULL then the join should occur only on 'column1' of **df1** and 'col1' of **df2** but if it is **not** NULL/blank then the join should occur on two conditions, i.e. 'column1', 'column2' of **df1** with 'col1', 'col2' of **df2** respectively.

For reference the final dataframe that I wish to obtain is:

[image: df3]

My current approach is that I'm trying to slice these 2 dataframes into 4 and then joining them seperately based on the condition. Is there any way to do this without slicing them or maybe a better way that I'm missing out??

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @jezrael That's true for most programming questions, but in this case where the formatting is cleaner with the picture and not dependent on its precise content, I actually prefer the picture more.

Comment: @user3576467 - Hard testing solutions from pictures...

Comment: @jezrael got your point but I'm just trying to explain the structure of the dataframe as clearly as possible

Comment: @YashAggarwal - Picures are super, but please also add sample data in text ;)

Comment: @jezrael will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is `rename` columns before left join by both columns first and then replace missing value by matching by `column1`, here is necessary remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) before [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for unique values in `col1`:

```
df22 = df2.rename(columns={'col1':'column1','col2':'column2'})
df = df1.merge(df22, on=['column1','column2'], how='left')
s = df2.drop_duplicates('col1').set_index('col1')['col3']
df['col3'] = df['col3'].fillna(df['column1'].map(s))
```

EDIT: General solution working with multiple columns - first part is same, is used left join, in second part is used `merge` by one column with [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) for replace missing values:

```
df22 = df2.rename(columns={'col1':'column1','col2':'column2'})
df = df1.merge(df22, on=['column1','column2'], how='left')
df23 = df22.drop_duplicates('column1').drop('column2', axis=1)
df = df.merge(df23, on='column1', how='left', suffixes=('','_'))
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.endswith('_')]

df = df.combine_first(df[cols].rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip('_'))).drop(cols, axis=1)
```

Comment: Also if there are more columns in df2, should I use the same statement as df['col3'] again or it can be clubbed in that last line you mentioned??